# Why T-SQL automatically rollback transaction when try to truncate column size?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a question about a T-SQL behavior that I can't find a explaination of.

I set up a simple table

```
create table SavedData (
    textData varchar(5)
)
```

when I run the following sql, the first row is inserted

```
begin transaction
    insert into SavedData values (1, 'asd')
    insert into SavedData values (1, 'asdasdad') //exception here
commit transaction
```

but when I run those, no row is inserted

```
begin transaction
    insert into SavedData values (1, 'asd')
    alter table SavedData alter column textData varchar(2) //exception here
commit transaction
```

In both cases, an exception will be thrown in the second statement. But why the final result is different?

Comment: I have trouble to connect the title of the question with its contend. There are 2 completely different questions asked.

Comment: And what are the different different results?

Comment: 1 tx is rolled back entriely, 1 tx has 1 record saved. Hooman answered why.

Comment: Aaaaah, now I see it. And again I learned something new. (a good start into the day :) )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the transaction rolled back, on the first exception, you need to 
set XACT_ABORT ON, [See here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-xact-abort-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

> **SET XACT_ABORT { ON | OFF }**
>
> Specifies whether SQL Server automatically rolls back the current
>   transaction when a Transact-SQL statement raises a run-time error.

If you have XACT_ABORT OFF (which is the default) then there is no guarantee that the entire transaction will be rolled back:

> When SET XACT_ABORT is ON, if a Transact-SQL statement raises a
>   run-time error, the entire transaction is terminated and rolled back.
>
> When SET XACT_ABORT is OFF, in some cases only the Transact-SQL
>   statement that raised the error is rolled back and the transaction
>   continues processing. Depending upon the severity of the error, the
>   entire transaction may be rolled back even when SET XACT_ABORT is OFF.
>   OFF is the default setting.